# ggplot not showing all x-axis ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to show all the years on the x-axis using "seq(1999,2003,1)", but for some reason it is not working. How do I show all the years on the x-axis with 1 year intervals? So it looks like 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003.

```
col1 <- c(1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003)
col2 <- c(5,4,3,4,3)
col3 <- c(4,3,1,3,5)
df <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3)
dfmelt <- melt(df, id.vars="col1")
ggplot(dfmelt, aes(x = col1, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col () +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=(seq(1999,2003,1)), limits = c(1999, 2003))
```

[image]

Running this without scale_x_discrete shows all 5 years, but in my actual data, this is not the case, so I'm wondering if there is something wrong with the way I tried to plot this.

TIA

Comment: Years column is numeric, not factor.

Comment: ... switch to `scale_x_continuous`.

Comment: @stefan thank you. When I switch to scale_x_continous, the first bar and last bar do not show and I get this response "Removed 4 rows containing missing values (geom_col)." Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: can u try to do ```x = as.factor(col1)```

Comment: Aw. Sorry. Remove the limits.

Comment: @stefan Wow, it's working properly in the example and my actual data. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved by using `scale_x_continuous`

```
ggplot(dfmelt, aes(x = col1, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col () +
  scale_x_continuous()
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so, then please consider marking it as the accepted answer by clicking on the tick mark beside the answer, and if it has been useful then please also consider upvoting by clicking on the up arrow.